GeoServer gives 403 for bearer token with OpenID
I am configuring GeoServer for OpenId connect authentication.

Generate access token with user log into GeoServer via web or postman.
Use that access token as bearer token to do Postman calls to access layers and its working.
But if I create access token without user log in. If I create access token with OpenId APIKey concept and then use that access token as bearer token to call GeoServer; I am getting 403

